# Installing a program without auto starting it after installation - 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, autostart, tomcat8

I have a simple problem. I am installing `tomcat8` using `apt install tomcat8` and it starts automatically after installation. I do not want it to start right after installation, however I want to keep auto-startup at boot setting.

The issue is that I want to configure it after initial installation, then do the first start myself when configuration is ready. Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does that automatically. I just do not want it to started by `apt` after installation.

Comment: 0k it's clear now..